# How can I calculate the complexity of my longest path problem?

Tags: c, graph, time-complexity, longest-path

I need to find the longest path in which the values of the points are getting bigger. First I find the number of steps of the longest path, and then I use DFS to search all the point in my map and see if they offer a solutions with that number of steps.

As I run al the map to discover the number of steps, I know it will be at least O(L*C) being L and C the size of the map. But I can't find what to do next.

```
void dfsRA(VERTICE** mapa, int L, int C, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

    a=0;
    mapa[x2][y2].pre = cnt++;
    int X=x2,Y=y2;


    //Vai procurar os adjacentes no mÃ¡ximo de oito direÃ§Ãµes
    for(int n=0; n<8;n++){

      if(n==0){
        x2=x1+1;
        y2=y1+1;
      }

      if(n==1){
        x2=x1+1;
        y2=y1;
      }

      if(n==2){
        x2=x1+1;
        y2=y1-1;
      }

      if(n==3){
        x2=x1;
        y2=y1+1;
      }

      if(n==4){
        x2=x1;
        y2=y1-1;
      }

      if(n==5){
        x2=x1-1;
        y2=y1+1;
      }

      if(n==6){
        x2=x1-1;
        y2=y1;
      }

      if(n==7){
        x2=x1-1;
        y2=y1-1;
      }

    //Verifica se o adjacente existe no mapa
    if(x2<L && x2>=0 && y2>=0 && y2<C){
      //Verifica se o adjacente ainda nÃ£o foi visitado e se o seu valor Ã© estritamente maior
      if(mapa[x2][y2].pre == -1 && mapa[x2][y2].valor>mapa[x1][y1].valor && i>0){
        i--;
        a++;
        auxiliar++;
        mapa[x2][y2].caminho= auxiliar;
        dfsRA(mapa, L, C, x2, y2, x2, y2);
      }}


      x2=X;
      y2=Y;
    }

    //Realiza o backtrack caso chegue a um ponto onde Ã© impossivÃ©l continuar
    //e limpa o vetor pre e retira o ponto do caminho(soluÃ§Ã£o)
    if(a==0 && i >0 && arraysize(mapa,L,C)>0){
      mapa[X][Y].caminho= 0;
      auxiliar--;
      mapa[X][Y].pre= -1;
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right, i defined i as const int, sorry i forgot to mention.

Comment: static int, sorry